# Swift - BLE peripheral.discoverServices() only find the first service the the array

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to find two services and their characteristics. `bluetoothPeripheral.BatteryService, bluetoothPeripheral.NordicUARTService`

But when I call: `peripheral.discoverServices([bluetoothPeripheral.BatteryService, bluetoothPeripheral.NordicUARTService])`,
the `didDiscoverServices`- delegate function only finds the first service in the array.

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    if peripheral == myDevice {
        
        print("Connected to  \(peripheral.name ?? "") \(peripheral.identifier )\n\n")


        peripheral.discoverServices([bluetoothPeripheral.BatteryService, bluetoothPeripheral.NordicUARTService])
        
        
    }
}

// Delegate - Called when services are discovered
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    if let services = peripheral.services {
        for service in services {
            
            // Discover Battery Service
            
            if service.uuid == bluetoothPeripheral.BatteryService{
                print("Battery Service found")
            }
            
            // Discover UART Service
            else if service.uuid == bluetoothPeripheral.NordicUARTService{
                print("UART Service found")
            }
            //discovery of characteristics
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics([bluetoothPeripheral.RxChar,bluetoothPeripheral.TxChar, bluetoothPeripheral.BatteryLevelChar ], for: service)
            
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Battery Service found
---Characteristic found with UUID: Battery Level 

Battery char found
<CBCharacteristic: 0x...., UUID = Battery Level, properties = 0x12, value = {length = 1, bytes = 0x7f}, notifying = NO>
```

How can I find multiple services at the same time?
It works, when I search for both services in seperate functions, but not both in one array.

Comment: I recommend adding an `else` leg to your `if-else` stack. Check if there is only one element in there, or if there are more and you're just wrong about the ID.

Comment: If I use `print (service)` at the very beginning of the for-loop in `didDiscoverServices`, I only get the battery service: `<CBService: 0x280098f80, isPrimary = YES, UUID = Battery>`.
Shouldn't that list all services, including the UARTService?

Comment: I would first suspect that your UUIDs are incorrect. Use `nil` as the list of services to request all services and make sure you have the right UUIDs. You can also use a tool like LightBlue to better check what the device is advertising.

Comment: In case I use nil, I only get the UART service instead. So the UUIDs seem to be correct.

Comment: You only get the UART and not the battery service? `nil` should return all services. That sounds like a firmware bug.

Comment: That's really weird. If I only try to discover the UARTService, without Battery, I find the UARTService.